# Can a wizard keep a cockatrice as a familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, familiars

I have a wizard character who has a pet cockatrice. Although the animal is not on any list of familiars, is there an official or unofficial way to make my petrifying chicken into a familiar?

(Also, if there's any information available that explains *why* a cockatrice is absent from the list of wizard familiars, I'd be interested in reading it.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Standard [Familiars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) are all creatures of less than 1 CR.

A [Cockatrice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/cockatrice) is CR 3.

A Wizard with the [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar) feat can choose from a list of more powerful creatures, but must have a minimum caster level to do so. There are only a couple of CR 3 creatures on the list, and they require caster level of 7 or higher.

Comment: I will look into it. My current caster level is 5, so there should be no problem getting the feat any time soon.

Answer (score 16):

A cockatrice is too strong to use as a regular familiar. It has high ability scores, decent skill ranks and a petrifying bite, making it too powerful for your average low level wizard. But if you just want a cockatrice for the flavor of having a cockatrice, you could use the rules for 'approximating familiars' as [read here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar). You could use the stats of a chicken or peacock. Just imagine it's a runt or something.